# Animation plays when walking left but not right

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation

I have created two animations: "Walk" and "Idle" and I made the transitions from "Idle" to "Walk" and from "Walk" to "Idle" as well.

When I go the the left side, the "Walk" animation is being played, but when I go to the right, the animation doesn't play.

Here is my Movement Function:

```
void PlayerMovement()
{
    tempPos = transform.position;
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (h > 0)
    {
        //tempPos.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
        //sr.flipX = false;

    }
    if (h < 0)
    {
        //tempPos.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
        //sr.flipX = true;
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("WalkParam", false);
    }
    transform.position = tempPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be more obvious if we adjust the whitespace in your code like so:

```
if (h > 0) {
    animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
}

if (h < 0) {
    animator.SetBool("WalkParam", true);
} else {
    animator.SetBool("WalkParam", false);
}
```

See how the case that checks for movement to the right is completely separated from the case that checks to the left?

So let's step through this code for a frame when `h > 0`:

1. We hit the first `if` and pass the test, so we enter the block.
2. Inside this `if` block, `"WalkParam"` gets set to `true`.
3. We resume execution at the end of the first `if`'s block, since it has no attached `else if` or `else` blocks to skip over.
4. We hit the second `if` and fail the test, so we skip to the `else` block.
5. Inside this `else` block, `"WalkParam"` gets set to `false`.

So we finish this function with `WalkParam` set to false.

You can fix this by changing your second `if` to an `else if`, so it's only executed if the first `if` test fails, and skipped otherwise. That joins the full `if`-`else if`-`else` into one chain, where exactly one of their contained blocks will be executed. Without this joining keyword, each `if` will be checked independent of the previous test's outcome.

But you can actually do all this much more simply:

```
// Use approximate comparisons for floats,
// in case of small rounding errors
if (Mathf.Approximately(h, 0)) {
    animator.SetBool("WalkParam", false);
} else {
    // Use one branch for both walk directions.
    // Less repetition = fewer places for bugs.
    float step = Mathf.Sign(h) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(step, 0, 0, Space.World);
    animator.SetBool("WalkParam", false);
    sr.flipX = h < 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that it was missing "else if". Instead, I had written just "if". So, the problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.